# How to add values in list in Cypress

Tags: list, cypress

I want to add values in a list.
I am trying like this to store value in list. Not sure how to add them.

```
cy.get('td.text-right:nth-child(7)').each(($ele) => {
list.push($ele.text().split(',').join('').split('$')[1].trim())
cy.log(list)
```

`your text`
In log I am getting two lists instead of one. Not sure why I am getting 2 lists. Can someone please help in storing the value in list and adding them.

I want to store values in list and add those values.

Comment: Is this not because you are calling cy.log() inside of the `each` callback? It will fire every time it loops over.